Determining radius of the circle spinning around a point with sparse measurements
I need help determining the radius of the circle by taking sparse measurements from a certain point.
Point C is the center of circle. Radius of the circle is the distance between points C and D. This circle spins around point P at a constant speed. We take measurements from point M and resulting measurement value is the x-value of point E plus some random noise. We can take as many measurements as we like. Point D is a single point at the circle and illustrates how the circle is spinning.
Here is the animation
System Overview (Spherical shape in the image is a circle even though it looks like an ellipse)
picture

What we know:

We know the distance between M and P
Line between points M and P is horizontal i.e. they are located at the same y
Point P and M are fixed
Distance from P to C does not change
We know angle of unit vector from P to C related to x-axis at all times

What we do not know:

We do not know distance from P to C
We do not know the radius of the circle

Clarification of measurement data:
Let's say we take measurements between [0, 360] degrees at the interval of one degree. We get 360 measurements and each measurement is the x-value of point E in that specific angle. As said, we know the angle of the system for each measurement.
To illustrate measurements, they could look like this:
[M0:(x=5, angle=0), M1:(x=5.1, angle=1), M2:(x=5.2, angle=2.01) ... M359:(x=5, angle=359)]
Now that measurements are taken, we would like to calculate the radius of the circle that produces these measurements. The problem is that because the circle is spinning around point P with unknown offset P to C, if measurements are mapped to 2D with their angle and measurement value it produces an ellipse. Eventually I would like to manipulate the measurement data to a form of an approximate circle so I can mathematically fit a circle to the measurement points to get the radius.
Any help is appreciated.

We know the coordinates of which points?

You could try computing point $E$ in terms of the angle $\theta$.

Where is point $E$ located? Is it $D$?

The ellipse in the picture is actually a circle. It appears as an ellipse because you chose different units on the $x$ axis and the $y$ axis. It seems clear to me that the maximum value of $x_E$ is $r+d$ where $d = PC$ and $r=CD$. The minimal value of $x_E$ is $r - d$. Knowing $r+d$ and $r-d$, you can find $r$ and $d$.

@Gribouillis you are right, but as said, there is noise with each measurement so the method you are proposing is not an optimal solution. I think we should use as many measurements as we can to determine exact radius.
